# how to show RGB images in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

I have a RGB dataset like that:

```
   [[ 255 165 0]
    [255 255 0]
    [0  255 0]]
```

I want to show each row's color,separate 3 PNG images, each 64x64 pixels 
Is there some method existed in matplotlib or opencv?

Comment: Do you mean you have a text file with those three lines in it and you want to make an image 3 pixels tall and 1 pixel wide? Are you struggling with reading the text file? Or with making an image? Or with seeing something so small?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the problem has been modified

Comment: So what will the result be? 3 separate PNG images, each 64x64 pixels so you can see them? Or maybe a TIFF file that is 3 pixels wide and 1 pixel tall?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your reply again, I want to separte 3 images, first one is 255 165 0,  second is 255 255 0, third 0  255 0, and each one can be seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **OpenCV** (and most other Python imaging libraries) an image is represented by a Numpy array. So, if you want to make a 3-channel (i.e. colour) image full of [255, 165, 0] you just need:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Make 64x64 pixel colour image
im = np.full((64,64,3), [255,165,0], dtype=np.uint8)

# Save to disk
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

Note that **OpenCV** uses BGR ordering, so if your 3 values are in fact RGB, you need:

```
im = np.full((64,64,3), [0,165,255], dtype=np.uint8)
```